# not executing testNG file in maven

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a testNG script in my maven project but when i execute `mvn test` that script not executing

pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>xgen</groupId>
  <artifactId>smart_collect</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>smart_collect</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

here is my script in the test package

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Login {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public String baseUrl;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {



        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        //driver = new ChromeDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        baseUrl = "https://www.google.lk/";
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test
    public void login() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']")).click();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
         driver.quit();
    }

}
```

my folder structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwVHV.png)

My maven output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBnoq.png)

Need to know why is this happening. this is working fine when i run it with testNG

Answer (score 1):

POM doesn't know which file to run. Follow below steps to make it work.

Create a testng.xml file and add below code at before   pom.xml and try to run.

```
 <build>
        <!-- Source directory configuration -->
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <suiteXmlFile>suites-test-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be usedfor compiling
                the code -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```